# parse/loop through this data and print name and merchant using javascript

Tags: json, object, nested-loops

```
aqw= {
    "res": {
        "statiscs":{
            "traffic": {
                "0": {
                    "name": "S0",
                    "bytes": 87
                },
            "1": {
                "name": "S1",
                "bytes": 837
            },
            "3": {
                "state": [
                    {
                        "merchant": "seno",
                        "vendor": "miami"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "S1",
                "bytes": 837
            }
        }
        }
    }
}

console.log('...', aqw.res.statiscs.traffic.0.name);
```

I tried using console.log('...', aqw.res.statiscs.traffic.0.name) but I got undefined.
I tried using angular ng-repeat but stuck at accessing dynamic numeric key

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the number dot notation. Use Bracket for this.

```js
aqw= {
    "res": {
        "statiscs":{
            "traffic": {
                "0": {
                    "name": "S0",
                    "bytes": 87
                },
            "1": {
                "name": "S1",
                "bytes": 837
            },
            "3": {
                "state": [
                    {
                        "merchant": "seno",
                        "vendor": "miami"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "S1",
                "bytes": 837
            }
        }
        }
    }
}

console.log('...', aqw.res.statiscs.traffic["0"].name);
```